# Can't serve Django static files with NGINX

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Django and React website using gunicorn, nginx and docker.

I can't get nginx to read my static files for example the django admin panel. I already ran `python manage.py collecstatic` and the files are in `recommendations-be/backend/static`

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./recommendations-be
    command: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 0
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - static:/django/backend/static
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./recommendations-fe
    volumes:
      - react_build:/react/build
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx-setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - react_build:/var/www/react
      - static:/django/backend/static
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
volumes:
  static:
  react_build:
```

Here is my nginx conf file:

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        root /var/www/react;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /django/backend/static;
    }

}
```

Here's the `Dockerfile` in backend directory `recommendations-be`:

```
FROM python:3.10.8-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /django

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

COPY . .
```

And the django `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "backend", "static")
```

Here is the file structure in my project: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNaHu.png)

Comment: two things to try. **#1** make sure `cd /django/backend/static` put you into the correct directory, it's the full path. **#2** Change your `location /static/` -> `location /static` , (no end slash) that's how I have it in my nginx settings

Comment: Unfortunally it still doesn't work, can't get nginx to find the static files

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx configuration, please make the following change:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /static/
}
```

Then, in your docker-compose.yml file, in the volume definitions of **Nginx**, please replace the line

```
- static:/django/backend/static
```

with the following:

```
- static:/static
```

Nginx should now be able to serve your static files.